# how to create this numpy array？

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to vstack the arrays that I created, why does temp only contain one array at the end?

```
i = 0.8
while i <1.5:
   temp= []
   d = np.random.choice([3,i],size = 10, replace=True,p =[0.5,0.5])
   temp.append(d)
   i+= 0.1;
```

Comment: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: what do you get in `d` ? Is it array or single value ?

Comment: create `temp = []` before `while` . Now you delete previous data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create `temp = []` only once - before `while`.

Using `temp = []` inside loop you delete value from previous loop so finally you get only values from last loop.
    import numpy as np

```
temp = []

i = 0.8
while i <1.5:
   d = np.random.choice([3, i], size=10, replace=True, p=[0.5, 0.5])
   temp.append(d)
   i += 0.1

print(temp)
```